# How to label a text with multiple paragraphs in AWS Ground Truth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, text, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I was trying setup a single label labeling task in AWS Groundtruth through the console. My goal is to match some users in social media and for each user I have several possible candidates out of which one should be selected (label). My CSV looks like this:

```
firtname | lastname | candidates

Romeo      Montague      x
Juliet     Capulet       x
```

Instead of "x", I would like to have something like this

```
candidate_1
description_1
link_1

candidate_2
description_2
link_2

candidate_3
description_3
link_3
```

The human worked should then select whereas the correct label is candidate_1, candidate_2 or candidate_3 or none of the above.

I am aware Sagemaker ground truth does not accept new lines characters and that it renders it in HTML so I tried to input the following:

```
candidate_1 <br/> description <br/> link <br/><br/> candidate_2 <br/> description <br/> link <br/><br/> candidate_3 <br/> description <br/> link <br/><br/>
```

unfortunately, when I take a look at the console, the input on the left does not render correctly:

[image]

The line breaks within the div tag seem to be simply ignored by the UI.

I found [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=302236) which contains the answer but I am struggling to adapt to my concrete use case.

How can I change my csv so that the multiple paragraphs get rendered corrected?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I have now in a very similar situation as you did.

Comment: No, I was very disappointed with the usability of the tool... I discovered labelstudio which can pull and push data from s3. I find it sooo much better.